# How to see all the locations of missing features in Test-SPContentDatabase?

Tags: content-migration

On running Test-SPContentDatabase, for features that are missing in more than four places, the "Locations" object shows "...". Is there a way to get the complete list instead of only four?

Below is the script that I'm using

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -Name <DBName> -WebApplication <WebApp> -ServerInstance <Instance> -ShowLocation
```

And this is the output (Pasting only Location Parameter due to company restriction)

> Locations       : {ef596e52-355d-496c-a0a0-4295dcc353f8,
>   133137b6-1a4e-4f4c-92c4-42b6d5872f8f,
>   781a90c7-403c-43a8-9ff5-44a1a46940aa,
>   aa88a9ed-1528-4190-89e7-4695d9737981...}

Answer (score 1):

I think you can overcome the `limited view` in PowerShell console by **Exporting** the output to `CSV` file using **Export-Csv** cmdlet as the following:

```
Test-SPContentDatabase -Name <DBName> -WebApplication <WebApp> -ServerInstance <Instance> -ShowLocation | Export-Csv -Path "c:\data.csv"
```

Comment: That doesn't help. In the csv under Locations column am not getting any location instead it's just showing the data type (System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPTestResultLocation])